# Visual Studio 2010 Professional não exibe Visual Studio Solutions

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Visual Studio 2010 Professional que tem em Add-> New Project-> Other Project Types não exibe Visual Studio Solutions.

Vi vários *posts* na internet indicando para solucionar o problema os seguintes passos:

Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solution marcar as opções: Shown Advanced build Configuration e Always show solution.

No meu caso todas as opões estão marcadas e não aparece.

[image: SS]

Comment: @bigown Reinstalei o Visual Studio e funcionou, era algum bug. Como proceder com o post, deixar em aberto ou teria com fechar e dar como resolvido?

Comment: Responde você mesmo para outras pessoas que tenham o mesmo problema poderem aproveitar. E pode aceitar a resposta.

Comment: Ok.Obrigado pela dica!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após reinstalar o pacote do Visual Studio 2010 a opção "Visual Studio Solutions" voltou a aparecer.
Era algum bug da primeira instalação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]